# How does one handle Date/Time component Overflow for Conversion to DATETIME2?

Tags: t-sql, datetime2

Supposing you have the following atrocious data structure in your SQL Server database to hold Date Times.

- Year (int)
- Month (int)
- Day (int)
- Hour (int)
- Minute (int)
- Second and Millisecond (float)

And you need to keep it but create a computed `DATETIME2` column based upon it, and in your data in one of your fields overflows its real capacity (e.g. "Second and Millsecond" holds 60 or greater) and you want to convert these fields into a `DATETIME2`; how can you do this so that any overflowing values cascade into a higher date/time component?  For example, the following invalid DateTime data would convert as follows:

- 2018-01-01 10:00:60.111 ► 2018-01-01 10:01:00.111
- 2018-12-31 23:59:61.123 ► 2019-01-01 00:00:01.123
- 2018-01-01 10:00:120.000 ► 2018-01-01 10:02:00.000

With my particular problem the data I've seen is only overflowing on seconds and seconds should only be 2 digits so they won't overflow by more than 1 minute, so a solution just for this would suffice for the immediate data.  However, I don't like that we've got to keep these int and float fields in our database to hold Date Times and would ultimately like a more bullet-proof means of handling any kind of overflow (and underflow too for completeness).

I don't mind whether the component fields are re-assigned to to make them valid for a `DATETIME2` or the new `DATETIME2` computed column is assigned the converted result directly and the bad data remains in the component fields; just so long as the computed column for `DATETIME2` can be persisted.

Comment: You could use _check constraints_ to ensure that invalid data can't be stored in the table or _triggers_ to validate and normalize the data. A _persisted computed column_ could be used to make the `DateTime2` value available without having to assemble it every time it is needed, and it can be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, my idea is:

1, Use 0 as the Seconds firstly,

2, add Seconds from SnM (Seconds and Milliseconds)

3, add Milliseconds from SnM.

Be careful of data type conversion issue...

Try this:

```
select 
dateadd(millisecond, cast(reverse(substring(reverse(cast(cast (SnM as decimal(10,3)) as varchar(50))),1,3)) as int),
dateadd(second, cast(substring(cast(cast (SnM as decimal(10,3)) as varchar(50)),1,charindex('.',cast(cast (SnM as decimal(10,3)) as varchar(50)))-1) as int), 
cast(concat(year,'-',month,'-',day,' ',hour,':',minute,':00') as datetime2))) as newdate
from test
```

Test Result:

[SQL<>Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d34d1/7)